# Changing minimal pricing in 1.9.3.7

Tags: pricing, featured-product, magento1.9.3.7, advanced-pricing

[image]I am trying to remove the "as low as pricing" in the Magento Admin Panel, can someone point me to where I can delete it from the links?

[image]

Comment: Delete special price for that product. Then it will disappear

Comment: Hi Teja, so I don't have any special pricing in Magento that would populate the "As low as:" price.... Any other thoughts on where it might be? I have removed the attribute, so the tiered pricing this originally came from is gone from the product description pages, but still shows in the featured products, sale, bestsellers, and popular products tabs on our homepage.